# NetSuite Saved Search Of Transactions Referencing Items

Tags: netsuite

I have to do some searches of a couple of different types of transactions, excluding with certain permutations of items.

The first one I have is a search of Orders excluding those which have any of a particular list of items.

Note that I don’t want to just exclude that item – I want to exclude the entire Order if any of its items are in the ‘exclude’ list.

The ‘exclude’ list is quite long, so I can’t use the ‘Item On Any Line’ search field. I’d have used a formula but the ‘Item On Any Line’ field isn’t available in a formula.

So how can I exclude Orders based on whether or not they have any of a list of particular items?

The second one I have is a search of Quotes excluding those which have only items on a particular list of items.

This search excludes a Quote only if ***all*** of its items are in the exclude list. So if the Quote has ten items and nine of them are on the list, then it should be included. But if all ten are on the list, it should be excluded. But how do you say “all items = x”?

I would think I’d need to somehow enumerate all the items in each quote, checking for any of the items, but I’ve no idea how to do that.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance